# Angular js функция внутри контроллера, дубли области видимости

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Добрый день, начал изучать Angular.js вот смотрю пример:

```
phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
 }]);
```

Мне стало не понятно, зачем дважды указывать область видимости всяких сервисов, провйдеров и прочего. Сначала в квадратных скобках, затем в функции, ведь можно просто написать:

```
  phonecatControllers.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope, $http){
     $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
     $scope.phones = data;
  });

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
 });
```

Что от этого измениться? Не будет дубляжа.

Answer (score 3):

> Angular js функция внутри контроллера

Она не внутри. Эта функция и есть контроллер.

---

> Что от этого изменится? Не будет дубляжа.

Пока ты используешь код как есть, не изменится ничего. По крайней мере, если ты не накосячишь в именах, указав их в разном порядке, например...

Но на нормальных сайтах принято js-код минифицировать. Вот я беру первый попавшийся online-сервис минификации (попался http://jscompress.com/) и скармливаю ему твой код.

```
// Первый:
phonecatControllers.controller("PhoneListCtrl",["$scope","$http",function(o,e){e.get("phones/phones.json").success(function(e){o.phones=e}),o.orderProp="age"}]);

// Второй:
phonecatControllers.controller("PhoneListCtrl",function(o,n){n.get("phones/phones.json").success(function(n){o.phones=n}),o.orderProp="age"});
```

Как во втором случае angular должен оапределить, что инжектится в функцию? Так что это всё-таки не совсем дублирование. Хотя, если есть специальный минификатор под ангуляр (не в курсе, сделали его всё-таки, или нет), то он бы мог сделать это сам.

Ну и ещё из плюсов. В случае с массивом ангуляр сразу знает, что ему инжектить и экономится время на парсинг функции. Но это так. На это вообще обращать внимания не стоит.

Кстати, есть ещё один способ перечисления зависимостей - через $inject.

Comment: Вероятно, автор взял неудачный пример, или прочитал через строки. Надеюсь, верно понимаю, что это от сюда https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 \\TODO `CTRL+F -> A Note on Minification`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanov, а в чём неудачность примера?

Comment: Если он не из оригинальной статьи, то вопрос минимализации мог быть пропущен, к сожалению.

Comment: Т.е. весь вопрос и вся польза от этого лишь в минификации дальнейшей? Можете скинуть ссылку на тот минификатор который схавает и без.

Comment: @Anatoly, не понял вопрос.

Comment: @Anatoly , [и код станет устойчив к минификации](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/ru-RU.md#minification-and-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Так делают для того, чтобы не было ошибок при минификации через таск-раннеры

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.